# Asp.net file-upload event

Tags: asp.net

I am using a file-upload object on my webpage with an "upload" button and a "Status" label. When a file is successfully upload the label's text changes to "File uploaded". If a user would like to upload another file, I want to clear the label text because as it still says "File Uploaded". Not sure how to do this. Please help.

Comment: post your code please.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the instantiating a new FileUpload object or clearing the FileUpload attributes are the best leads, as mentioned in this existing SO question:

Here is a similar SO question [How to clear file upload text in server side (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593573/how-to-clear-file-upload-text-in-server-side-c)

Answer (score 0):

You have two way to do this:

**client side**

Page will be reloaded if file uploaded, you just need to clear the label when page is loaded.

**Server side**

You can clear it with setting the text of "Status" label to blank after your codes handling uploaded file.